# C# Windows Store App - File IO using async/await causes timeouts and InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-async

this is my first post on this site and I searched high and wide to get my code to work.
Like the title says, it's a WinRT App and I'm having difficulty with File IO. What I want to do is read in a text file stored in a folder that is inside the application installation directory and that contains lines of data that I'll feed into an List<>.

```
public static async void GetStations()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(@"MyApp\Data\file.txt"))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        string line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                        //do something with 
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

the problem is I am getting file not found errors when trying to run it. Can anyone help? If you require that I post more information, I can...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ^ Sorry...the same error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are distributing your file as a part of your application package then `Package.Current.InstalledLocation` is the right location. `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` contains only files that have been put there by your application.

The correct code would be:

```
public static async void GetStations()
{
    try
    {
        using (var stream = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(@"Data\file.txt"))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                    //do something with 
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The file must be included in you project inside `Data` folder and have `Build Action` set to `Content`.

Comment: I still am getting the System.IO.FileNotFoundException error
The file is set to Content and Copy to Output Directory is set to Always

Comment: @kpfogey Did you include the file in your project as I described below the code? I created a working sample app which you can download from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10676122/App19.zip).

Comment: Ok I tried the code you gave me and it indeed works...somethings wrong with my app.
Does it matter where you use it? can it be used during page loading or a page constructor instead of an event?

Comment: @kpfogey It shouldn't matter where you use it. You can always try calling the same code from an event handler just to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening from `ApplicationData`, you probably need:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync
```

This will get the file in the package's installation folder, instead of the Application's *Data* folder.